# How to get index 0 and 1 from javascript json

Tags: javascript, json

I have json format that i need to get first index value (audio 0) and second index value (video 1) in a loop so i can't figure out how to get from json array using index 0 and 1....i im getting error using this jsfiddle...

```
 var info = '{"streams": [{"index": 0,"codec_name": "aac","codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)"}, {"index": "1","codec_name": "h264","codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG4 part 10"}]}';

 console.log("vcodec: "+info.streams[0].codec_name);
 console.log("vcodec: "+info.streams[1].codec_name);
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rbcofvg/)

Comment: You should add the relevant code to the question itself

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking, as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var info = '{"streams": [{"index": 0,"codec_name": "aac","codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)"}, {"index": "1","codec_name": "h264","codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG4 part 10"}]}';

var parsedInfo = JSON.parse(info);

console.log("acodec:", parsedInfo.streams[0].codec_name);
console.log("vcodec:", parsedInfo.streams[1].codec_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your fiddle, `infos` is a string. You have to use

```
JSON.parse(string)
```

To actually get the JavaScript object, and use it. To be more specific:

```
const infoString = '{"streams": []}'
const infoObject = JSON.parse(infoString)

console.log(infoObject.string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the double quotes to make it a json and use the following code it will work perfectly

```js
var info = {"streams": 
            [
              {"index": 0,"codec_name": "aac","codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)"}, 
             {"index": "1","codec_name": "h264","codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG4 part 10"}
            ]
           };

console.log(""+info.streams[0].codec_name);
console.log(""+info.streams[1].codec_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the json string before proceeding.

```
var info = YOUR_JSON ;
var parsedInfo = JSON.parse(info);
var codecName = parsedInfo.streams[0].codec_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the `json` string first. You are currently using string which cannot be indexed in `javascript`. Please find the attached code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
    var info = '{"streams": [{"index": 0,"codec_name": "aac","codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)"}, {"index": "1","codec_name": "h264","codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG4 part 10"}]}';
    info = JSON.parse(info);
    console.log("vcodec: " + info.streams[0].codec_name);
    console.log("vcodec: " + info.streams[1].codec_name);
</script>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```